# Deploying Web API to Azure - Entity Framework Core migrations connection string not being picked up

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to deploy my Web API to an Azure App Service using Visual Studio 2022, however when I try to apply the migrations, it is not discovering the connection string although it discovers the database context:

[image]

This is the code of my database context class:

```
namespace MyPortfolioWebAPI.Data
{
    public class MyPortfolioContext:DbContext
    {
        public MyPortfolioContext(DbContextOptions<MyPortfolioContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Emails> Emails { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<Projects> Projects { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

This is my `appsettings.json` file:

[image]

It works fine on my local machine, however I am trying to publish it to Azure.

Comment: am i suppose to add the connection string on apply this migration on publish manually or is it supposed to auto generate it like i thought

Comment: MayBe you can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936382/configure-my-connection-string-in-the-azure-application-setting-and-configure-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `appsettings.json` file like below. The issue should be fixed.

```
{
   "Logging": {
     "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
     }
   },
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Your_Connection_String"
   },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

---

I test in my local and use .net6 project. And found `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString` can directly identify the element under the key of `ConnectionStrings`.

Your code has one more layer of `Data nested`, that's why it can't be read.